# Neo4j data modeling POJO for relationships

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using Spring Data with Neo4j, and I am creating POJOs for my schema. In this schema I have a node called Person, with the usual attributes, name, lastname, etc... I also have a relationship called DRIVES which establishes a relationship with another node called carModel:

```
(person)-[:DRIVES]->(carModel).
```

In my Person class, I have defined all the property fields and an annotation for the relationship and method as following:

```
@Relationship(type = "DRIVES", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
public CarModel carModel;
```

My question is, if in the CarModel class do I need to define the relationship as well ?

Answer (score 1):

It is completely fine to create a model which declares the relationship only on one side.

The reasons for it might be

- you simply don't want to refer from your CarModel class to Person
- saves time during save operation on `CarModel` - SDN does not need to check if related `Person` has changed

**UPDATE**

The relationships stored in Neo4j are traversable in both directions, despite being defined only in Person class.

Using custom cypher queries you can query Person by CarModel and also CarModel by Person.

When using [derived finders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_queries_derived_from_finder_method_names) in SDN you can only use the direction which is defined in your class model.

Comment: Thanks Frant, a follow-up question based on your answer. I know that on the Neo4j browser, I am able to search for all people who drives a given type of CarModel. In the case if I define the relationship only on the Person object, would I be able to get the same kind of information about people who drives a given CarModel ?